# C - Copying a char to another

Tags: c, char, strcpy

I am a beginner in C language. I want to copy a char array to another, but I cannot. I got these errors:

```
Line 10 - [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'insert' makes pointer from integer without a cast
Line 4 - [Note] expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char'
```

Can you help me with finding the errors in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void insert(char d[100]);

int main( ) {

    char m[100];
    scanf("%s", &m);
    insert(m[100]);
    return 0;
}

void insert (char d[100]) {
    char s[200];
    strcpy(s, d); 
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &m);` --> `scanf("%99s", m);`  . And check the return value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `m` to `insert()` not `m[100]`. In that context,  `m[100]` represents a single element of the `m` array and not the array itself. That's why the "integer to pointer without a cast" warning, because `char` is an integer after all.

Comment: `m[100]` is actually out of bounds, so is UB.

Comment: @DavidBowling That too.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The function signature of `main()` should be one of:

```
int main(void) {}
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {}
```

or equivalently,

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {}
```

There is no need to use the address operator `&` with an array argument in `scanf()`, since arrays decay to pointers to their first elements in most expressions, including function calls.

Note that you should specify a maximum field width when using the `%s` conversion specifier with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflows:

```
scanf("%99s", m);
```

It is adquate to declare the `insert()` function as:

```
void insert(char d[]);
```

When you call the `insert()` function, only use the name of the array that you want to pass as an argument; this will decay to a pointer to the first element of the array. It is worth pointing out that the original code had undefined behavior with:

```
insert(m[100]);
```

This attempts to access the element at index 100 of the array `m[]`, which is out of bounds.

The code now looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void insert(char d[]);

int main(void)
{
    char m[100];
    scanf("%99s", m);
    insert(m);

    return 0;
}

void insert (char d[])
{
    char s[200];
    strcpy(s, d);
}
```

Now, I don't know what you intend to do with the copied string `s`, but it no longer exists after `insert()` returns control to `main()`.